# fullpage horizontal slider

Tags: twitter-bootstrap, fullpage.js

I am using  **fullpage.js** with bootsrap. My *sections* have auto-height, because of that somethings wrong with the horizontal slider ,it won't display any text.Here is the code:

```
<div class="section fp-auto-height">
        <div class="container">
            <div class="row">
                <div class="heading">header text</div>
                <div class="slide" id="slide1">Horizontal slider1</div>
                <div class="slide" id="slide2">Horizontal slider2</div>
            </div>
      </div>
</div>
```

any ideas why it's not working?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Have you read fullpage.js documentation regarding the [required HTML structure](https://github.com/alvarotrigo/fullPage.js#required-html-structure)?

The structure for the slides should look like this:

```
<div class="section">
    <div class="slide"> Slide 1 </div>
    <div class="slide"> Slide 2 </div>
    <div class="slide"> Slide 3 </div>
    <div class="slide"> Slide 4 </div>
</div>
```

So...

- Remove your `row` element
- Remove your `heading` element.
- Remove your `container` element.

  Horizontal slider1
      Horizontal slider2

If you want a header for all your slides in that particular section, then it will have to use `position:absolute` and the section `position:relative`:

```
<div class="section fp-auto-height">
    <div class="header">Demo</div>
    <div class="slide" id="slide1">Horizontal slider1</div>
    <div class="slide" id="slide2">Horizontal slider2</div>
</div>
```

Css

```
.header{
    position:absolute;
    top: 0;
}
.section {
    position:relative;
}
```

[Reproduction online](http://jsfiddle.net/97tbk/1199/)

Comment: it means I can't use bootstrap?

Comment: Not at all. It means you have to use it properly and apply it inside the slides and not outside them.